# Accumulated value of force of interest

Tags: integration, finance

> For the period from time 0 to time 2, the force of interest is defined as follows:
>   $$\text{force of interest at }(t) = \begin{cases}
> 0.05 & 0 \lt t \le 1\\
> 0.05+0.02(t-1) & 1\lt t \le 2
> \end{cases}$$
>   $10,\!000$ is invested at time $0$. Find the accumulated value at time $1$ and at time $2$.

I got the correct answer  for accumulated value at time $1$ using the accumulation function
$$A(t)=A(0)\exp\left(\int_0^T\text{force of interest}\ \mathrm dt\right),$$
by taking the integral of $0.05$ at $1$ and $0$, and then I ended up with $A(t)=10000(e^{0.05-0})$, which gave me $10512.7109$, the correct answer.

However, when I try the same steps but with $T=2$, and the only thing changing is that I take the integral of the second equation and then plug in the same formula, I am getting the wrong answer. The answer in the book is $11162.78$. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The integral should include both the first and second equation. You have to break the integral up as $\int_0^2 = \int_0^1 + \int_1^2$ using the appropriate part of the definition in each integral. Generally speaking, that's the only way to integrate a function that is defined piecewise if the interval of integration laps over different pieces of the definition.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting the wrong answer it means that you're not integrating correctly. When computing
$$\int_0^2\text{force of interest}\ \mathrm dt$$
you have to remember that the force of interest is defined by a piecewise function, and therefore you must split the integral. We get (writing $f(t)$ instead of $\text{force of interest}$):
$$\begin{align}
\int_0^2 f(t)\,\mathrm dt &= \int_0^1 f(t)\,\mathrm dt + \int_1^2 f(t)\,\mathrm dt =\\
&= \int_0^1 (0.05)\,\mathrm dt + \int_1^2\left(0.05 + 0.02(t - 1)\right)\,\mathrm dt =\\
&= 0.11
\end{align}$$

And indeed, $10000e^{0.11} = 11162.78$.

Answer (score 0):

Let be the force of interest defined by
$$
\delta(t) = \begin{cases}
0.05 & 0 \lt t \le 1\\
0.05+0.02(t-1) & 1\lt t \le 2
\end{cases}
$$
Integrating $\frac{A'(t)}{A(t)}=\delta(t)$ from $t_1$ to $t_2$ we have 
$$
A(t_2)=A(t_1)\mathrm e^{\int_{t_1}^{t_2}\delta(u)\mathrm d u}
$$
So we have
$$
A(1)=A(0)\exp\left(\int_{0}^{1}0.05\,\mathrm d u\right)=A(0)\mathrm e^{0.05}=10,000\,\mathrm e^{0.05}\approx 10,512.71
$$
where $A(0)=10,000$.

And 
$$
A(2)=A(1)\exp\left(\int_{1}^{2}[0.05+0.02(u-1)]\,\mathrm d u\right)=A(1)\mathrm e^{0.06}=10,512.71\,\mathrm e^{0.06}\approx 11,162.78
$$